# Error en move_uploaded_file PHP

Tags: php, mysql, upload

intento realizar un cargado de algun archivo directamente mysql. Al momento de la carga. arroja inmediato el mensaje"
[image: ERROR]
Tengo el sig codigo PHP

```
<?php
include_once 'conexionpdf.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    
     
 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="uploads/";
 
  $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 
  $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 
 
 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
 
 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))  // -----LINEA DEL ERROR   
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
  mysql_query($sql);
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='admin.php?success';
        </script>
  <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
```

Investigué, y encuentro que el destino del archivo debe existir o tener permisos. Pero no encuentro de qué manera darle permisos, o no se si tenga un error en el destino.
De esta manera tengo la BD por si es de utilidad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Los errores son claros, el primero te dice que el archivo o directorio no existe, mientras que el segundo te dice que no ha podido mover un archivo temporal a la carpeta uploads.

1. Comprueba que las rutas y ficheros realmente existan en el disco
2. Asegúrate que el usuario actual del sistema operativo tenga los permisos adecuados
   sobre el directorio y los respectivos ficheros
3. Comprueba los permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución tanto de los directorios y archivos en cuestión

Tu problema está en el entorno de ejecución, no el código.